# How to select certain child nodes in xpath?

Tags: xpath

If I have some XML structure like this

```
     A
  B    C
D  E  F  G
```

So `A` has two children nodes `B` and `C`, and `B` has two children nodes `D` and `E`, and `C` has two children nodes `F` and `G`. How can I write an xpath to select `E` and `G`? I'm looking for a way to union two selectors something like `/A/(B/E)|(C/G)`.

I was trying something like

```
/A/B/E + /A/C/G
```

but that has syntax errors...

Comment: How about `//E | //G`?

Comment: What if you had to put a predicate for the A one like A[@m="1"]?

Comment: Get XPathBuilder here: http://www.bubasoft.net/product/xpath-builder/  It's a free utility.

Comment: @omega then perhaps you should have mentioned that in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built an XML input from your scenario above, as follows:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <D>DDD</D>
        <E>EEE</E>
    </B>
    <C>
        <F>FFF</F>
        <G>GGG</G>
    </C>
</A>
```

if you run this query:

```
/A[B]//E|/A[C]//G
```

it outputs:

```
<E>EEE</E>
<G>GGG</G>
```